# Is it ok to make RFC822 messages that use LF and not CRLF?

Tags: rfc822

The [RFC822/RFC2822 standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) says that "Header fields are lines composed of a field name, followed by a colon (':'), followed by a field body, and terminated by CRLF".

But I see at least [one RFC822 MIME parser](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-0.3.4/docs/src/Codec-MIME-Parse.html#parseMIMEBody) that auto-normalizes payloads that use LF ("\n") into CRLF ("\r\n") before proceeding with parsing.

How safe is it to use an RFC822 format for serializing data that may have been hand-edited in places to use LF instead of CRLF? Would it be safe to send this data around to different programs & expect them to be able to parse it with various RFC822 parser libraries?

Comment: Do you have some strong reason to do this?

Comment: It would be nice to be able to hand edit some of the RFC822 representations if necessary, and inserting CRLF is a hassle in editors on *nix.

Comment: Be lax with your input and Be strict with your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, not safe at all. Be conservative in what you send / generate.

Having said that, most Unix tools expect locally stored email files to use local line ending conventions. RFC5322 really only codifies the format used on the wire.

Comment: It looks like MTAs like Postfix strip the CRs before it saves email to a user account in /var/mail/file or into mbox format.